# Sort list based on pattern

Tags: python, list

I'd like to know how I can easily generate a list based on the values/order of two other lists:

```
list_a = ['web1','web2','web3','web1','web4']
list_b = ['web2','web4','web1','web5','web1']
```

I'd like to retrieve the "list_b" list ordered by value from "list_a":

```
final = ['web1','web2','web1','web4','web5']
```

If an entry exist on list_b but not on list_a, then the value is appended to the list at the end.

I'm not sure where to start, my initial thinking was to retrieve all the indexes with enum `[i for i, x in enumerate(mylist) if x==value]`, then sort the list, but I'm having hard time managing entries with multiples index (eg: web1) . Just wondering if you guys are thinking about an easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: "I'd like to retrieve the "list_b" list ordered by value from "list_a":" - can you please provide more information about this?

Comment: I don't understand your sorting mechanism - how do you determine which value is where?

Comment: Just iterate over list_a asking if element in list_a in list_b, keep adding it to the third list final while removing the matched item from list_b. Then append the remaining contents of list_b at the end of final? What will you gain by sorting the list?

Answer (score 1):

An extremely simplistic way would be to just iterate over `list_a`, and should you find each element in `list_b` you remove it and append it to a list. Then after iterating all that remains in `list_b` are the elements that you need to add to the end of your list.

```
list_a = ['web1','web2','web3','web1','web4']
list_b = ['web2','web4','web1','web5','web1']

front = []
for ele in list_a:
    if ele in list_b:
        front.append(ele)
        list_b.remove(ele)

final = front + list_b
print(final)
```

**Outputs**:

```
['web1', 'web2', 'web1', 'web4', 'web5']
```

---

Another trickier way would be to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a few list comprehensions, leveraging the set intersection and difference of the counters.

```
from collections import Counter

cnt_a, cnt_b = Counter(list_a), Counter(list_b)
intersct = (cnt_a & cnt_b)
diff = (cnt_b - cnt_a)

final = [a for a in list_a if a in intersct] + [b for b in list_b if b in diff]
```